# Is sysctl.conf last match?

Tags: sysctl

Where can I find the official documentation that `sysctl.conf` is last match based?

So, there are two entries in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
vm.swappiness=10
vm.swappiness=11
```

Which will win? The last one? What happens if there are files in the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory?

Comment: What if you run the experiment above and find out? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t think there is any such official documentation. `sysctl` entries are handled by [`procps`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) and systemd; but neither projects’ documentation address how entries are processed within the same configuration file.

The short version is that the last entry in `sysctl.conf` wins, even when other files are present (in `/etc/sysctl.d` or elsewhere), regardless of which system is used to load the settings.

### `procps`

To understand how `procps` processes entries, we need to look at [the source code for `sysctl`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/sysctl.c). This shows that later entries are processed without knowledge of earlier entries, so the last one wins (look at the `Preload` function). When multiple configuration files are given on the command line, these are processed in order, as described in [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html):

> Using this option
>                 will mean arguments to `sysctl` are files, which are read in the
>                 order they are specified.

Things get a little more complex with the `--system` option, but at least that’s documented:

> Load settings from all system configuration files. Files are
>                 read from directories in the following list in given order
>                 from top to bottom.  Once a file of a given filename is
>                 loaded, any file of the same name in subsequent directories is
>                 ignored.
>
> - `/run/sysctl.d/*.conf`
> - `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`
> - `/usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`
> - `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`
> - `/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`
> - `/etc/sysctl.conf`

The documentation isn’t quite complete. As mentioned above, entries within a given file are applied in order, and overwrite any value given to the same setting previously. In addition, looking at the `PreloadSystem` function show that files are processed in name order, and that `/etc/sysctl.conf` is processed unconditionnally (*i.e.* an identically-named file in an earlier directory doesn’t override it).

### systemd

systemd has its own `sysctl` handler, which is documented in [the `sysctl.d` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html); that has a section on precedence:

> Configuration files are read from directories in `/etc/`, `/run/`, and `/usr/lib/`, in order of precedence. Each configuration file in these configuration directories shall be named in the style of *`filename`*`.conf`. Files in `/etc/` override files with the same name in `/run/` and `/usr/lib/`. Files in `/run/` override files with the same name in `/usr/lib/`.
>
> […] All configuration files are sorted by their filename in lexicographic order, regardless of which of the directories they reside in. If multiple files specify the same option, the entry in the file with the lexicographically latest name will take precedence. It is recommended to prefix all filenames with a two-digit number and a dash, to simplify the ordering of the files.

Again, later entries within a single configuration file override earlier entries.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this assertion in a more practical way:

First things first: Values will not be applied if you prefix the `sysctl` word on your `sysctl.conf` entries("*manpages are lol*" as you said but you didn't seem to have seriously read them). And, it's an easy task to test this: Put the following content at the end of your `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
vm.swappiness = 60
vm.swappiness = 61
```

I'm using swappines here cause i know that it's a low impact sysctl to mess arround with little difference values depending on your system load (and the default value is 60 on most distros). Apply only this file by typing `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`[(manpage)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl). Double-check the value with `sysctl -a`

```
root@host:~# sysctl -a | grep "vm.swappiness"
vm.swappiness = 61
```

Voilá.

Now that you know files are read on a top-down approach, it's just a matter of reading [`sysctl.d`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.d.5.html) manpage to figure out what is the precedence on spread sysctl files across you system. As it's already explained by @Stephen Kitt answer, i'll not repeat this info here.

Also, this `sysctl.d` directories precedence will depend if the distro you are using is systemd-based or not...

Comment: removed the "sysctl" from the examples, just a typo, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this in the future, and your system doesn't have procps (RHEL, CentOS, etc), you'll find that "systemctl --system" and "systemd-sysctl.service" apply the directories in different orders, so be aware of the ordering of the files for override by filename.  For overriding by sysctl, the last value read is applied, so the ordering of the filenames *and* the ordering of the directories matters.